# Is it possible to implement a clipboard manager using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a JavaScript-based clipboard manager for a particular website, but I'm not really sure where to start. Since most web browsers don't allow the clipboard contents to be directly accessed, is there any other way to store a list of clipboard items that the user has copied from a particular web page, without storing any duplicate items?

Comment: use [zeroclipboard](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard) ?

Comment: @adeneo zeroclipboard requires Adobe Flash, and I'd prefer to use a pure JavaScript implementation.

Comment: That's just it, there is no cross browser pure javascript solution. IE supports access to the clipboard, and Chrome now supports some access to the clipboard, but for a cross browser solution you have to use flash.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the copied text by detecting the `CTRL+C` key combination, add the selected text to an array, and then remove any duplicate elements from the array, so that no duplicate clipboard items are stored.

If you wanted to store the HTML that the user had copied (instead of just storing the text), you could use a JavaScript library such as [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/).

Here is a demonstration that displays all text that the user has copied from the page, without showing any duplicate clipboard items:

http://jsfiddle.net/2RdRD/1/

```
var arrayOfCopiedText = new Array();
$(window).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 67) {
        arrayOfCopiedText[arrayOfCopiedText.length] = window.getSelection().toString();

        //remove duplicates from the array
        arrayOfCopiedText = removeDuplicates(arrayOfCopiedText);

        alert("List of current clipboard items: " + JSON.stringify(arrayOfCopiedText));
    }
});

function removeDuplicates(names) {
    var uniqueNames = [];
    $.each(names, function (i, el) {
        if ($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
    });
    return uniqueNames;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use execCommand if you have a ui to let the user copy to clipboard and store that value in the dom somewhere.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla

Comment: Which browsers support this feature?

Comment: IE for sure, and there's probably more than handful of jquery plugins that make it cross browser.